# What is the equivalent of the java code SomeActivity.this in kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, zxing

I have a code that scans bar/qr code using zxing in java:

```
 IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(SomeScanActivity.this);
 integrator.initiateScan();
```

Here's how I did it in kotlin:

```
IntentIntegrator(this).initiateScan()
```

In java, the constructor for IntentIntegrator won't accept 'this' as a constructor parameter, but in kotlin it does accept 'this' as a constructor parameter. My suspicion is that this is the cause of the problem that I'm having where I get a null value on the result.

What is the correct equivalent of the java code in kotlin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's

```
this@SomeActivity
```

If you start typing `this`, you should see that appear in the suggested auto-completions.

Comment: That's correct, I just figure out that you can convert a java class to kotlin in android studio and that's what I got. Thanks for the answer, will mark it as correct.